# Vuejs + Laravel array issue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

My problem is I'm trying to loop and array from Axios query into my blade template, query is giving me no errors but tells me is undefined multiple times on my select tag.

I have a simple Axios query from my Laravel Controller:

```
public function consultaPersonas()
{
    $consulta = persona::all();
    if(!$consulta) {
        $consulta = ['error' => 'No hay registros'];
    }
    return $consulta;
}
```

this query will bring me this little array:

```
[
    {"cedula":"15678453","nombre":"LUIS CHACON","edad":30},
    {"cedula":"2536524","nombre":"MARIO ORTEGA","edad":21},
    {"cedula":"25632541","nombre":"VANESSA ALCALA","edad":24}
]
```

This is the Select Tag i want to loop:

```
<select class="form-control" v-model="nombre">
    <option v-for="nom in nombre">@{{ nombre }}</option>
</select>
```

Here's my Vuejs code:

```
var app = new Vue({
            el: '#root',
            data: {
                cedula: '',
                nombre: [],
            },
            watch: {
                cedula: function() {
                    this.nombre = ''
                    if (this.cedula.length == 1) {
                        this.buscarCedula()
                        this.nombre = "Consultando cédula...";
                    }
                }
            },
            methods: {
                buscarCedula: _.debounce(function() {
                    axios.get('http://localhost/miapp/public/personas/mostrar')
                        .then(function(response) {

                            let datos = response.data;
                            let validar = datos.error;

                            if (!validar) {
                                app.nombre =
                                    datos.cedula + ' - ' +
                                    datos.nombre + ' - ' +
                                    datos.edad;

                            } else {
                                app.nombre = validar;
                            }
                        })
                        .catch(function(error) {
                            app.nombre = error;
                        })
                }, 500)
            }
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I think you have to try return with JSON like 'response()->json($consulta)' from consultaPersonas()

Comment: Your code looks messy. First `nombre` is a model. In data, `nombre` is an array. In `buscarCedula()`, `nombre` is a string. Then suddenly you have `app.nombre`. Where is `app` coming from? What you should do is set `nombre` to the `response.data` in axios success. Then, you are looping through `nombre` and creating the variable `nom`. `nom` is an object, so you do `@{{ nom.nombre }}`

Comment: Does the answer come to you? I do not see a function call for the first request ...

Comment: Yeah, that´s right EddyTheDove, thanks, i posted below also another problem i had i noone notice.

Answer (score 0):

js:

```
created():
    axios.get('http://localhost/miapp/public/personas/mostrar')
    .then(function (response){
        this.nombre = response.data;
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    })
```

html:

```
<select class="form-control" v-model="nombre">
    <option v-for="nom in nombre">@{{ nom.nombre }}</option>
</select>
```

Next, you transfer from the created method call axios to methods, and in created call this method. This initializes your initial data

Comment: Yes Oleg Shleif, at the HTML that's the solution for looping my data, but at my JS i used a return this.nombre = response.data becasuse otherwise it was failing when i need to return multiple values. Thanks a lot, also i posted my own question with solution.

Answer (score 0):

I find out what was wrong,

I had two problems, one was my view tags variables, this is the right way since i need to loop through my nom object with his index like this:

```
<select class="form-control" v-model="nombre">
    <option v-for="nom in nombre">@{{ nom.cedula }}</option>
</select>
```

the second problem was my return at my vuejs file, i was returning one single output into a loop, this is the right way:

```
    var app = new Vue({
                el: '#root',
                data: {
                    cedula: '',
                    nombre: [],
                },
                watch: {
                    cedula: function() {
                        this.nombre = ''
                        if (this.cedula.length == 1) {
                            this.buscarCedula()
                            this.nombre = "Consultando cédula...";
                        }
                    }
                },
                methods: {
                    buscarCedula: _.debounce(function() {
                        axios.get('http://localhost/miapp/public/personas/mostrar')
                            .then(function(response) {

                                if (!response.data.error) {
                                    return app.nombre = response.data;

                                } else {
                                   return app.nombre = response.data.error;
                                }
                            })
                            .catch(function(error) {
                                app.nombre = error;
                            })
                    }, 500)
                }
)};
```